# Assign Elastic IP to one instance in AWS autoscaling group

Tags: amazon-web-services, autoscaling, aws-auto-scaling, elastic-ip

I have an autoscaling group in AWS with 3 instances. The use case I am working on requires one of the EC2 instances to have an Elastic IP. The 3 instances I have are in separate availability zones (us-east-1a, us-east-1b, us-east-1c). My plan is to associate the Elastic IP to an instance using the launch configuration user_data attribute. The problem is if I do that, that script gets executed on all 3 instances, which I do not want. I need the script to run on only one instance since I need the Elastic IP only to be associated with 1 instance. Is there an easy way to achieve this? One approach is to use a separate autoscaling group for the instance that needs the Elastic IP, but I would like to keep all 3 instances in 1 autoscaling group. Any advice would be helpful.

Comment: Could I ask... _Why_ do you need an Elastic IP on one of the instances?

Answer (score 1):

Theres no way of only running a user data script on 1 instance in an ASG - you need to add logic to your userdata script to decide if it should attach the IP or not when that specific server starts.

As your planning on attaching the IP from the instances userdata its not much more work to get the current attachment state of the Elastic IP - if its not attached, attach it, if its already attached just exit the script as theres nothing to do?